# What happens when using multiple field on fieldsgrouping?

Tags: apache-storm

Assuming we have an event stream with events with the following two attributes:

```
{"first_name", "last_name"}
```

and we partition on both attributes using *fieldsgrouping*:

```
.fieldsgrouping{"spout", new Fields("first_name", "last_name")}
```

The processing bolt is parallelized by two tasks and the following events enter the stream in specified order:

```
1: {"foo", "foo"}
2: {"bar", "bar"}
3: {"foo", "bar"}
```

Now events 1 and 2 go to task one and two respectively, what will happen with event 3? If it goes to either task it will break *fieldsgrouping* of an attribute.

How does Storm handle this? Or am I not understanding *fieldsgrouping* correctly?

---

**Edit:**

Thinking about this a bit more I probably misunderstood the behaviour of *fieldsgrouping*. If both fields are considered coupled event 1, 2, and 3 are each considered a distinct partition. Removing the problem.

However, this is not immediately clear from the only official [documentation](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Concepts.html) I can find on *fieldsgrouping*.

If anybody could point me to more detailed documentation.

Comment: Your own observation is correct. The three tuples belong to a different "logical partition" each because they are not equal over all fields. Thus, there is no problem. I also think, the documentation is exact (maybe not complete): "Fields grouping: The stream is partitioned by the fields specified in the grouping. [...]" It says "fields", ie, plural. Even if the example only uses one field for grouping, if you extrapolate this, it is clear that for multiple grouping fields, all fields values must be the same  if two tuples belong to the same group/partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by first name by last name, meaning that not all tuples with the same first name will end up on the same destination, but tuples with the same first name and last name will.

[Storm Applied](https://www.manning.com/books/storm-applied) (Sec 3.5.3) has a good example of this based on grouping street checkins by time-interval and city instead of using only time-interval. Basically, the latter was creating a bottleneck of all street checkins in the same interval ending up in the same bolt, no matter the city. By adding city to fields grouping, they kept the requirement of having all street checkins in the same bolt and at the same time they removed the bottleneck.